# Adding custom field to WSO2 EMM

Tags: wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

When I'm adding a user to WSO2 EMM, I enter the following attributes: username, first name, last name, email, type and rules.

1. How can I add more attributes (like company name or phone number) when creating a user?
2. Is there a way to send these attributes (current and new) to another server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Indeed yes. But you need to change the UI for this. Saving is the same way as we have done for other parameters. This will be saved as a claim in identity server component databases.

2) You will need slight modifications to the code. There is no restriction from doing it. Check jaggeryjs.org and look into XMLHttpRequest section since EMM uses Jaggery.